# unix_chkpw run before access.conf via pam - security risk

Tags: security, redhat-enterprise-linux, pam

I have RHEL 6.3 systems that have PAM's access.conf correctly configured and running.  However, it seems in a less than ideal state, after analysis of a root-hack attempt, and I'm wondering if there's anything that can be done about it.

I used authconfig to add access.conf and then added my rules.  However, it looks like PAM runs a password check BEFORE running access.conf rules.  I want to reverse that, and not even allow someone to check password unless they pass access.conf rules FIRST.

The current behavior represents a security risk, imho, because although access.conf might subsequently deny a successful password guess, there are characteristics that will tell the hacker that they got the guess right.  That is:

Unsuccessful password attempts:

```
[ivo@pioneer:~]$ ssh root@mysecuresystem
root@mysecuresystem's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
root@mysecuresystem's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
root@mysecuresystem's password:
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Successful password attempts:

```
[ivo@pioneer:~]$ ssh root@mysecuresystem
root@mysecuresystem's password:
Connection closed by 10.10.10.65
```

Behavior doesn't conclusively tell them they got password, but it IS different from a failed guess, and therefore noteable.  (Also, logs still show unix_chkpw, which results in a false positive in Security's IDS/log analyzer).

While changing this behavior would result in PAM source changes, and thus be complicated, changing the order of checks in PAM might be easy?

So how do I get PAM to use access.conf BEFORE a password check?

(Note: We need to use access.conf because we need to stop only root from most machines, but allow users from anywhere.  So sshd config is not a solution, nor are wrappers for what we need to accomplish)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a solution but it seems to be a reasonable workaround, modify /etc/pam.d/sshd moving the "pam_access.so" line so that it's in the "auth" section, for example:

auth       required     pam_access.so

Rather than

account    required     pam_access.so

This causes log in attempts to produce the "Access denied" message even when a valid password has been used thus avoiding informing the hacker of a correct guess.

Comment: Thanks Bill - I think this is a partial answer, and if after a few more days no one else answers will mark it as such.  This solves the part where the cracker will get same prompting whether they guess correctly or not.  I would love to see the logs still not show unix_chkpw so our security group would quit coming down to "make sure this is a false positive..."  But this solves a big part!